# Flutter StreamBuilder flashes with data then clears

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I'm trying to build a page in Flutter that shows all the comments made by a user.  For some reason, this stream builder loads the data, flashes it briefly, then acts as if there is no data.  I'm sure it has something to do with the way my query/stream is built.  Thanks for any help!
**Update**
I've discovered it is when I use the ".where" query that causes the problem.

This works great:    `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('comments').snapshots()`

This loads correctly for about half a second then has no data:     `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('comments').where('uid', equalTo: uid).snapshots()`

Code:

```
child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List<CommentCard> commentList = [];
          final comments = snapshot.data!.docs;
          for (var comment in comments) {
            commentList.add(CommentCard(
                comment: Comment.fromSnapshot(
                    comment, comment.reference.parent.parent!.id)));
          }
          commentList.sort();

          return Column(children: commentList);
        }
        return const Text("You have made no comments");
      },
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collectionGroup('comments')
          .where('uid', isEqualTo: currentUser.uid)
          .snapshots(),
    ),
```

Comment: You are creating the stream in the stream: parameter of the streambuilder, and it's refreshing the stream 60 times per second.  See this video for how that breaks it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you have any errors while fetching data from the network, as you may know retrieving data from network takes a while.

Try this code, hope it helps you.

```
 return StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('comments').where('uid', isEqualTo: currentUser.uid)
    .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.hasData)
        {
          List<CommentCard> commentList = [];
          final comments = snapshot.data!.docs;
          for (var comment in comments) {
            commentList.add(CommentCard(
                comment: Comment.fromSnapshot(
                    comment, comment.reference.parent.parent!.id)));
          }
          commentList.sort();

          return Column(children: commentList);
    }
      else if(snapshot.hasError)
        {
          return Text("You have no Comments");
        }
      else{
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
 }
 );
```

Comment: Thanks.  I discovered that my main problem was that when using collectionGroup in Firestore, you first have to setup some indexes as seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQ4u1J717ys

Comment: I am glad you found the solution; All the best